# Pokemon Go No Pokestops or Poke Gyms

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm Playing this game since 2 weeks, I'm an **iPhone** User suddenly pokestops and pokegyms disappeared from my map but when I **log in my account into another handset** it works fine...Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall the game on the iphone with problems.

Remove the app through settings and reinstall from the app store